# Get first / last value in column B where date in column A is X

Tags: excel, date, range, multiple-columns

Imagine 2 columns in Excel. Column A has dates, sorted, not unique. Column B as values for those dates.

Example Data:

Column A       Column B 
31/03/2014  -342 
31/03/2014  -338 
31/03/2014  -335.8 
31/03/2014  -333.8 
31/03/2014  -338.8
31/03/2014  -314.2
31/03/2014  -311
31/03/2014  -305
01/04/2014  -298.8
01/04/2014  -290.8
01/04/2014  -287
01/04/2014  -285.6
01/04/2014  -315.6
01/04/2014  -304.6
01/04/2014  -301.9
01/04/2014  -278.9
01/04/2014  -548.9
01/04/2014  -591.9
01/04/2014  -562.5
01/04/2014  -247.4
01/04/2014  -293.9

Now, I need to display in new cells:

- The value of Column B where the **first occurrence** of a given date in Column A is X
- The value of Column B where the **last occurrence** of a given date in Column A is X

In MySQL for example it would have been something nice and easy like: "SELECT Column_B FROM db WHERE Column_A LIKE 'x' LIMIT 1" (to get the first occurrence)

How do I do this in Excel? NB: I have experimented with Index, Match, VLookup, but can't seem to figure out how to get these conditions working.

Comment: Are the dates in ascending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For first occurrence** use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx):

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,A:B,2,0)
```

**For last occurrence** use [LOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lookup-function-HA102752947.aspx?CTT=1):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A=E1),B:B)
```

in both formulas `E1` contians target date:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Thanks for the super-fast response. Great job, especially for the last occurrence. Works a treat. Thank you!